# Does file type rely on file extension?

Tags: file, operating-system, file-type

As a general question: What's the role of file extension when determining file types?

For example, I can change .jpeg file to .png extension and even .txt. Of course, in the case of changing to .txt, it will neither be opened as picture, nor readable.

To determine file type, it seems the safe way is to parse the first few bytes of the file. If extension is not trustable, extension is no more than file name.

Comment: What do you mean by "what's the role"? You seem to have already identified most of the relevant concerns yourself…

Comment: @duskwuff I mean how much can I trust the extension. To some degree, the extension seems "redundant" comparing to parsing the first few bytes of a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, you should ALWAYS parse the COMPLETE file in order to be sure that the file is what the extension says. As you can easily imagine, it is pretty simple to create a binary file resembling a e.g. BMP (with a correct header) but then containing something different.

You should never trust the extension neither the header because otherwise a malicious user could exploit some of your code to generate e.g. a buffer overflow, and this is absolutely paramount if you are writing programs that must run at root/admin privilege.

Having said the obvious, the file extension nowadays is mainly used so that the OS can associate a program to that particular file (usually calling the program and passing the selected file as first parameter), and then it's up to the program to determine the file content.

It is a little bit different when talking about executable files. Under Unix, in order to be executable a file has to have the "x" flag set, otherwise it would not run, regardless of the extension. Under Windows, there is not such thing and the OS relies on only a few extensions (EXE, COM, BAT, etc.) to determine which files can be executed.

The EXE file, for example, has to start with "MZ" followed by some information for its allocation and size (http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/exe/) and the OS surely checks its internal headers. Other formats (e.g. the COM executable format of the MS-DOS era) is just "pure" assembly code, so there is no check done by the OS. It just interprets those opcodes, hoping that everything will be fine.

So, to summarize:

- File extension is mainly used so that the OS can call the appropriate program to open it (and passing the filename as the first parameter, argc/argv in C language for example)
- Windows relies on some file extension to know if a file is executable, while Unix/Mac relies on a particular flag (x) associated with the file

Two things that are not well known about file extensions: directory names can have extension too, and extension can be way longer than the usual 3 characters.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of file extension, you know how to read the first few and all the rest of the bytes. You also know what program to use to read the file. Or if it is an executable, you know that it is to be executed and not shown as a picture.

Yes you can change the file extension, but what does it mean then? It only means that OS (or any program that tried to read the file) is working correctly. Only you are providing bad data to it.

File extension is not something that some bytes of data inherently have. Extensions are given to those bytes depending upon the *protocol* followed to write them that way. After you have encoded the letters in binary form, you provide that binary form with .txt extension so that the text reader knows that these bytes convert to letters. That's the role of file extension. With bad file extension, this role is not fulfilled, resulting in incomprehension of the data you saved in binary.

Answer (score 1):

> As a general question: What's the role of file extension when determining file types?

The file extension usually identifies the **application** that opens a file.

If you rename a .JPG to a .PNG and while having JPG and PNG opened by the same application (usually an image viewer) that application can read the image stream and process it correctly regardless of having an incorrect file stream.

The problem arises if you rename the file in such a way that the file gets routed to an application that cannot handle the file's content.

If you rename a .DOCX (word) file to an Autocad extension (.DWG), opening the word file in autocad is likely to produce errors (unless per chance autocad can read word files).